# Django file upload does not work fine

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## models.py:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="File name", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')
    upload_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="uploader", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

## Serializer.py

```
class FileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ("id", "file", "upload_at", "user")
```

## views.py:

```
class FileView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser]
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    # @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.FILES)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Anythings works fine, but when uploads file images are damaged!

[image]

Where I make mistake?

---

## **UPDATE**

each uploaded file contains this line in file begins:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybe2fuJLynmLSubNO^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="2bc794eead99bf38140524ecbfa7e001_large.jpeg"^M
Content-Type: image/jpeg^M
^M
```

Why? How I can remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation mentions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser):

> The FileUploadParser is for usage with native clients that can upload the file as a raw data request. For web-based uploads, or for native clients with multipart upload support, you should use the MultiPartParser parser instead.

You should remove the `FileUploadParser` in your parsers or move `MultiPartParser` as the first one.